# SharePoint Records View

Tags: document-library, list-view

Good afternoon all, I am trying to create a records view and filtering it by declared as a record.

The below script is what I am trying to run and its saying completed, but it clearly has not.

Any ideas would be super useful.

```
Add SharePoint PowerShell Snap-in
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

Connect to SharePoint 2019
$siteUrl = "http://yoursharepoint2019site"
$listName = "Records"
$viewName = "FilteredView"

Create a new SharePoint list
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl
$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::GenericList
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)

if ($list -eq $null) {
    $listId = $web.Lists.Add($listName, "Description", $listTemplate)
    $list = $web.Lists[$listId]

   Add columns
    $list.Fields.Add("Type", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text, $false)
    $list.Fields.Add("Name", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text, $false)
    $list.Fields.Add("Title", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text, $false)
    $list.Fields.Add("CheckOutUser", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text, $false)

   Show all items in folder
    $list.ForceCheckout = $true
    $list.Update()
}

Create a view with the filter
$view = $list.Views[$viewName]
if ($view -eq $null) {
    $viewFields = $list.Fields | Where-Object { $_.InternalName -in @("ID", "Type", "Name", "Title", "Modified", "Editor", "CheckOutUser") }
    $viewQuery = "<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='Declared_x0020_a_x0020_Record' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Neq></Where>"
    $view = $list.Views.Add($viewName, $viewFields.InternalName, $viewQuery, 100, $true, $false)
}

$web.Dispose()

Write-Host "SharePoint list 'Records' and view 'FilteredView' created successfully."
```

Comment: sorry i am still getting used to this site and trying to find away of putting the actual PS script in